# Does random function does not executes again in repaint?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I am working on a code, where I am drawing multiple shapes on the JPanel and then calling repaint. I think that when I call repaint, the shapes in the JPanel should move to a new location as the random function will now provide different values. But the shapes do not move at all. Any ideas why is this happening?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Filter extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {  
                public void run() 
                {
                    Filter mainFrame = new Filter();
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
      }

    public Filter()
    {
        //Creating the JFrame main window
        setSize(800, 500);
        setTitle("Particle Filter");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        //creates two panels content and sidebar. Sidebar has null layout       
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,500));
        content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.getContentPane().add(content);
        JPanel sidebar = new JPanel();
        sidebar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        sidebar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,500));
        this.getContentPane().add(sidebar);
        sidebar.setLayout(null);

        //creates three buttons in sidebar
        JButton start_button = new JButton("START");
        start_button.setBounds(10, 75, 77, 23);

        start_button.addActionListener(new MainPanel());       

        sidebar.add(start_button);
        JButton stop_button = new JButton("STOP");
        stop_button.setBounds(10, 109, 77, 23);
        sidebar.add(stop_button);
        JButton reset_button = new JButton("RESET");
        reset_button.setBounds(10, 381, 77, 23);
        sidebar.add(reset_button);

        //calls the content_Walls class and sends the number of ovals to be generated
        content.add( new MainPanel());
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public MainPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680,450));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("START"))
        {
            repaint();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawParticles(g);
        createObstacles(g,150,225,100,40);
        createObstacles(g,500,300,40,100);
        createRobot(g);        
    }

    private void createRobot(Graphics g)
    {
        int x=0, y=0;     
        int robot_radius=50;
        ArrayList<Integer> robot_list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        robot_list=positionRobot(x,y);
        drawRobot(g,robot_list.get(0),robot_list.get(1),robot_radius);
    }

    private void drawParticles(Graphics g)
    {
        int n=1000; // n denotes the number of particles    
        ArrayList<Integer> list;        
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
           generateParticles(g);
        }
    }

    private void generateParticles(Graphics g)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list=positionParticles(x,y);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(list.get(0),list.get(1), radius, radius);
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionParticles(int x, int y)
    {
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(2,678); // bounds of x between which the particles should be generated
        y=randomInteger(2,448); // bounds of y between which the particles should be generated
        x=x-(radius/2);
        y=y-(radius/2);
        if((x<251&&x>=150)&&(y<266&&y>=225))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        if((x<541&&x>499)&&(y<401&&y>299))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        return list;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionRobot(int x, int y)
    {
        int robot_radius=50;   
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(25,655);//so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        y=randomInteger(25,425); //so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        x=x-(robot_radius/2);
        y=y-(robot_radius/2);
        if((x<250&&x>=150)&&(y<=265&&y>=225))
        {
           x=0;
           y=0;
           positionRobot(x,y);
        }
        if((x<=540&&x>=500)&&(y<=400&&y>=300))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionRobot(x,y);
        }
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        return list;            
    }

    private void createObstacles(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);   
    }

    private static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should trim that code down to what's actually relevant

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, this is happening due to the null layout? Is the repainting technique correct?

Comment: @user3097157 No, it's happening because you are creating multiple instance of `MainPanel`, the advice about `null` layouts is just general observations and advice for best practices...

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, how should i code things which require custom settings apart from null layout.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom settings"?  I personally would simply use something like `GridBagLayout` or even `MigLayout`...

Comment: I just meant more flexibility. I have to still learn GridBagLayout, seems a bit complex.I will try to change it through GridBag, once I learn it. Thanx btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58209/discussion-between-learningjava-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is, the instance of `MainPanel` that is responding to the `JButton` is not the same instance of the `MainPanel` that is on the screen...

```
// Instance one...
start_button.addActionListener(new MainPanel());
//...
// Instance two...
//calls the content_Walls class and sends the number of ovals to be generated
content.add(new MainPanel());
```

Instead, create a single instance and use it in both situations...

```
MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
start_button.addActionListener(mainPanel);
//...
//calls the content_Walls class and sends the number of ovals to be generated
content.add(mainPanel);
```

And when you get around to plugging in the functionality of the stop button, use the same instance again.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Was stuck on this for so long.

Comment: and see also GiCo's answer about not creating a new instance of random every time, too!  (while not the problem, it is a good suggestion!)

Answer (score 0):

That could be because you are using no seed value, for the cunstructor of Random. But not sure if this was also in Java or only in another language. (Reading the docs, maybe it was another language)

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

you can use the time as seed value:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

also it would be possible to make rand a field and only cunstruct it once:

```
private static Random rand;
private static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
{
    if (rand == null)
       rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Code  not testet. Sorry, I'm nearly sleeping.

Comment: As per the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()), the default constructor for `Random` will *"Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor."*...so I fail to see how this would be a problem...

Comment: Yeah have read it. I was remembering having this problem, but not sure in which language. :-)

Comment: I don't discount the idea of only creating a single instance of `Random` though, rather than recreating each time...